# Ensure state consistency by introducing a shared microservice?

Tags: architecture, microservices, saga

Let's say I have 2 entities(aggregate roots) in different microservices.

- Report(id, status = opened | in_progress | processed | closed, follow_up(custom form answers), investigation(custom form answers), ...)
- Inspection(id, form_answers, ...)

I have a requirement to add a possibility to fill the custom(dynamic) form during the lifecycle of these entities.

Forms are created by users and it **mustn't** be possible to fill Report specific form in Inspection and vise-versa.
Form structure(field types) and form submission(answers) model are the same among these entities.

My question is how to design it in microservices way, given the following domain constraints:

- it **must not** be possible to edit Report follow_up once it in *processed* status except for some specific users
- it **must not** be possible to edit Report follow_up when report is *closed*
- it **must** be possible to fill investigation only when Report is *processed*
- Form fields **should** be the same for every entity, which use custom forms

**Approach #1**

Introduce in each service a form entity and store answers in report/inspection respectively.

Pros:

- State consistency(status checks for changing form answers is done in one aggregate, so it's easier to follow domain constraints)

Cons:

- Code duplication(answers validation/entity structures/...)
- Adding new field type requires to change multiple services

**Approach #2**

Introduce a new form service to store user-defined forms and form answers. Entities should reference answers only by id.

Pros:

- Forms logic in one place

Cons:

- Hard to follow domain constraints without tightly coupling or lots of saga's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give a bit of generic answer:

A good microservices infrastructure is more about services solving specific business problems, and less about being interfaces for databases - this is a common mistake - a service literally looks like a proxy for database queries.

Let me extract service ideas from your description:

- "Forms are created by users": FormCreationService?
- FormFillInService
- ReportsService - it will have a state machine to make sure only correct transitions are allowed (e.g. no edit after completed)
- InspectionService - also with a state machine

The next step would be to describe API's for every service (please, find youtube video on "designing apis" very old talk at google).

Then you validate api's by sequence diagrams - as a result you may merge services - in case they are too small; or split larger chunks.

At the end of the day - you want to apply Unix philosophy for your services: "Do one thing and do it well".

Comment: thank you for response! By introducing a FormFillingService, how can I ensure that by filling some report form domain constraints aren’t broken(e.g. client sends request to fill report follow up, but report is already closed)? Should form filling service call report service directly for report state and wouldn’t it be a tightly coupling?

Comment: How is a report closed? Is it some time deadline? Or a manual action? The question is - when a customer starts to fill in a form, do they know how much time they have? For example, a form may come with "deadline" piece of data to handle UX.
In either way, additional check will be executed on submit to check if that specific submit is allowed.

Add a clarification: the report service may have an api: fillReport(data) - and the result of calling this api is either Done or AlreadyClosed or something else, like report does not exist. This seems like a legit api to have.

Comment: Report is closed by manual user action.

_In either way, additional check will be executed on submit to check if that specific submit is allowed._

The main concern here is by doing this check we can't guarantee consistency. It's possible scenario that during this check report is closed in another thread. More of that, FormFillingService should know directly about ReportService(which I want to avoid somehow)

Comment: _Add a clarification: the report service may have an api: fillReport(data)._

Good idea, but in this case I'd need to copy-paste form answers model among all services and it might end up in lots of changes if new answer type is added.

Comment: "we can't guarantee consistency" I don't see why not. FormFillingService knows about forms and it sends data to the ReportingService. The ReportingService knows if a report is open or not and can make a decision to either process or decline a request. As for copy-paste stuff - I would go with a dynamic forms - they don't know/don't care what are the fields - they ask for meta data from some authority (another service?) and execute. FormFillingService should not change just because forms or reports change.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Now I understand this idea much better.

Comment: few more words (no one can stop me :) ) - it's a typical "mistake" to first define a model and then try to split functions across microservices; as a result, the same model objects will be everywhere - e.g. there is a reportsService, but report model is everywhere, hence coupling. There is no silver bullet, but I try to group use cases (verbs, like fillForm, saveReport) and then see how the model looks like. Another way - write customer facing api, and then keep splitting them by services. Sometime I might be left with a single service - that's ok - it's not a must to have microservices.